# Convert laravel query as eloquent using relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I am learning laravel and although i have found a solution, i am curious if there is a "better" or more "laravel" way to do it. Here is the working solution i have:

(example 1)

```
$students = Subclass::query()
            ->join('student_subclass', 'subclasses.id', '=', 'student_subclass.subclass_id')
            ->join('students', 'students.id', '=', 'student_subclass.student_id')
            ->select('*')
            ->where('subclasses.id', $request->subclass_id)
            ->get();
```

I have 3 tables: subclasses, students and student_subclass as the pivot table. The above query correctly returns the students that belong to a specific subclass (from $request). **The important part, is that it also returns ALL the fields from BOTH tables. So in the collection i get, for each student, i also have the t_class_id field that exists only in the subclasses tables.**

If i want to use my relationship like:
(example 2)

```
$students = Subclass::findOrFail($request->subclass_id)->students;
```

It is much more elegant, but i only get the fields from the students table (and this is fine most of the time). So... is there a way to modify example 2 so that it also returns the fields from the subclasses table for each student? (those that are not in the pivot or students table). Or to rephrase it. Can we convert the example 1 to the type of example 2 and get exactly the results from example 1?

Comment: create another relationship in your `Students` model with one to many relationship? https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Create another relationship:

```
public function students(): BelongsTo {
    return $this->belongsTo(Student::class, 'students'); }
```

Comment: I already have the relationships and they are working as intended. This is not what this question is about. Thanks for your time though.